# Is there a way to left join two datasets into a third one at the same time?

Tags: r, join

I have a dataset(df1) that looks like this

```
ID     |New York Athletes
Base001 Aaron Judge 
Bask001 Kevin Durant
Bask002 Julius Randle
Base002 Max Scherzer
```

I want to merge in two other datasets at the same time while not adding extra columns

```
ID     |TEAM
Bask001 Nets
Bask002 Knicks

ID     |TEAM
Base001 Yankees
Base002 Mets

df1<- df1 %>%
mutate(merge(df1,Base,by="ID",all.x = TRUE))%>%
mutate(merge(.,Base,by="ID",all.x = TRUE))
```

However when i do this i get

```
ID     |New York Athletes|Teams   |Teams.x|Team.y
Base001 Aaron Judge       Yankees  Yankees 
Bask001 Kevin Durant                       Nets
Bask002 Julius Randle                      Knicks
Base002 Max Scherzer      Mets     Mets
```

I would like to get something like this

```
ID     |New York Athletes|Teams   
Base001 Aaron Judge       Yankees  
Bask001 Kevin Durant      Nets
Bask002 Julius Randle     Knicks
Base002 Max Scherzer      Mets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @KU99's answer is probably the simplest, but here's another option that uses `coalesce`.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~`New York Athletes`, 
"Base001", "Aaron Judge", 
"Bask001", "Kevin Durant",
"Bask002", "Julius Randle",
"Base002", "Max Scherzer")

df2 <- tibble::tibble(ID = c("Bask001", "Bask002"), 
                      TEAM = c("Nets", "Knicks"))

df3 <- tibble::tibble(ID = c("Base001", "Base002"), 
                      TEAM = c("Yankees", "Mets"))

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(merge(.,df2,by="ID",all.x = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(merge(.,df3,by="ID",all.x = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-TEAM) %>% 
  mutate(TEAM  = coalesce(TEAM.x,TEAM.y )) %>% 
  select(-c(TEAM.x, TEAM.y))

df1
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   ID      `New York Athletes` TEAM   
#>   <chr>   <chr>               <chr>  
#> 1 Base001 Aaron Judge         Yankees
#> 2 Base002 Max Scherzer        Mets   
#> 3 Bask001 Kevin Durant        Nets   
#> 4 Bask002 Julius Randle       Knicks
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: And why do you use `mutate(merge...`? Just `merge` is enough or use `left_join`

Comment: Because that was in the OP’s original code.

Answer (score 3):

In base R

```
merge(df1, rbind(df2, df3))

       ID New.York.Athletes    TEAM
1 Base001       Aaron Judge Yankees
2 Base002      Max Scherzer    Mets
3 Bask001      Kevin Durant    Nets
4 Bask002     Julius Randle  Knicks
```

Comment: Since the question asks for left join: `merge(df1, rbind(df2, df3), all.x=T)`

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer:
You actually need to do two separate joins for this. Leaving first attempt if you want to join multiple dataframes at once, for future reference.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(~ID, ~`New York Athletes`,
               "Base001", "Aaron Judge",
               "Bask001", "Kevin Durant",
               "Bask002", "Julius Randle",
               "Base002", "Max Scherzer")
df2 <- tribble(~ID,~TEAM,
               "Bask001", "Nets",
               "Bask002", "Knicks")
df3 <- tribble(~ID, ~TEAM,
               "Base001", "Yankees",
               "Base002", "Mets")


df1_1 <- full_join(df2, df3, by = c("ID", "TEAM"))
final_df <- left_join(df1, df1_1, by = "ID"); final_df
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   ID      `New York Athletes` TEAM   
#>   <chr>   <chr>               <chr>  
#> 1 Base001 Aaron Judge         Yankees
#> 2 Bask001 Kevin Durant        Nets   
#> 3 Bask002 Julius Randle       Knicks 
#> 4 Base002 Max Scherzer        Mets
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Yes you can use the `purrr` function to do multiple joins at once as so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(x = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"), y = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
df2 <- tibble(x = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"), z = c(4, 5, 6, 7))
df3 <- tibble(x = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"), delta = c(8, 9, 10, 11))

list_of_dataframes <- list(df1, df2, df3)

purrr::reduce(list_of_dataframes, left_join, by = "x")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   x         y     z delta
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A1        1     4     8
#> 2 A2        2     5     9
#> 3 B1        3     6    10
#> 4 B2        4     7    11
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Comment: I just edited my answer - didn't fully understand the question at first. Don't want to do all your joins at once here, since not all of tables have the requisite columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use {powerjoin}

```r
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, list(df2, df3), by = "ID", conflict = coalesce_xy)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   ID      `New York Athletes` TEAM   
#>   <chr>   <chr>               <chr>  
#> 1 Base001 Aaron Judge         Yankees
#> 2 Bask001 Kevin Durant        Nets   
#> 3 Bask002 Julius Randle       Knicks 
#> 4 Base002 Max Scherzer        Mets
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>